# GRASS 7 r.sun aspect in doubt

Tags: raster, aspect, grass-7.0

I'm using r.sun in GRASS 7.0.3 to determine beam irradiance at a site (~ 56N -4W).
I have a DEM (a local subset of [EU-DEM](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/digital-elevation-model/eu-dem-laea)).

I'm using r.sun in mode 2, called from GUI.

Typical logging in command output:

```
r.sun --overwrite --verbose elevation=EU_DEM+Trees6@PERMANENT aspect_value=120 slope_value=60.0 beam_rad=BeamIrrad_1021_T6_120as_60inc glob_rad=GlobalIrrad_1021_T6_120as_60inc insol_time=InsTime_1021_T6_120as_60inc day=284 step=0.25
```

Mode 2: integrated daily irradiation for a given day of the year`

I'm having trouble with the aspect value: this is described as degrees running CCW from East (here:[r.slope.aspect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.slope.aspect.html) and grass70/manuals/r.sun.html), with example that 270 = south.

However, I have undertaken multiple runs altering the aspect_value by 30 degree increments from 120 to 300, i.e. 330, 300, 270... 150 degrees from North.

On an unshaded hill-top, the results suggest that the peak beam irradiance is achieved for aspect_value = 180, i.e. 270degN (west). This is clearly wrong, and suspicious that it occurs at an aspect value that corresponds to South, if the aspect were specified in degrees from North.

The results:

aspect value: 300   270 240 210 180 150 120

equivalent bearing: 150 180 210 240 270 300 330

irradiance: 1161    1972    3323    4481    4881    4439    3268

So, is aspect_value in GRASS 7.0.3 really degrees CCW from east?

(as an aside, it's interesting that the text qualifying the 'aspect' tag notes that it is 'usually measure in degrees from north'...)

Comment: this seems to have been reported under 'issue 1' in http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2606